# How to find the indices of items fulfilling some condition in List of int?

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I have a list of int containing items { 10, 11, 23, 34, 56, 43 } and I want to find out the indices of all items which are greater than 23. These values can be any order so I do not want to sort them.

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int> { 10, 11, 23, 34, 56, 43 };
```

I am interested in indices of all items those are fulfilling the condition and not only first item which fulfill condition. so this line of code is not working for me.

```
int index = mylist.FindIndex( x => x > 23 );
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
var indexes = mylist.Select((v, i) => new { v, i })
                    .Where(x => x.v > 23)
                    .Select(x => x.i);
```

Comment: To get the first index of such as occurrence:  `_list.Select((v, i) => new {v, i}).Where(x => x.v.Priority > activity.Priority).Select(x => x.i).First();`

Comment: @gregsdennis `_list.Select((v, i) => new {v, i}).First(x => x.v.Priority > activity.Priority).i;`

Comment: @EdwinStoteler, okay. :)

Comment: Can someone explains how the `Select((v, i)...` works ? Why the `i` contains index ?

Comment: @A.Pissicat, easily:
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L47C37-L47C37  line 47 if I'm not mistaking

Answer (score 1):

Linq doesn't provide such a thing directly, but you could write your own. Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndices<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate) 
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (var item in items) 
    {
        if (predicate(item)) 
        {
            yield return i;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Then something like:

```
foreach (int index in mylist.FindIndices( x => x > 23 ))
    ...
```

(This has the advantage of being more efficient than the other approaches listed above. This is only significant for LARGE sequences though!)

Comment: This method returning a single value.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo in the return type.

Answer (score 0):

This extension method does the job, nice and clean:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the indices of all objects matching the given predicate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of objects in the list.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">The list.</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">The predicate.</param>
    /// <returns>Indices of all objects matching the given predicate.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndices<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return list.Where(predicate).Select(list.IndexOf);
    }
}
```

Check out the [working demo](http://ideone.com/NWL217)

Comment: Warning: this doesn't work if you have duplicate entries in the list (because of the `IndexOf`)

Answer (score 0):

A small variation to [rgripper's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1176284/rgripper) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14476218/1182982),

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int> { 10, 11, 23, 34, 56, 43 };
List<int> newList = mylist.Select((v, i) => new { v, i })
                        .Where(x => x.v > 23)
                        .Select(x => x.i).ToList<int>();
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/MsDjnZ)